# Lua sandbox _ENV with personal baselib (require, assert etc)

Tags: lua, sandbox, lua-api

*Lua 5.3.2*

I have a service written in Lua/C, that executes lua files in the same Lua_State.

I need to provide all the standard libraries for the file execution environment.

The simplest thing is to execute files this way: `loadfile(file_path, "bt", _G)`

The problem is: code in the file is able to corrupt the service's global state, so this method is not secure.

So, I need to create a sandboxed environment `loadfile(file_path, "bt", env)`

**The question**: how to register all the standard libraries from linit.c in the `env` variable?

I can simply register all the libs from the linit.c, except luaopen_base, because it contains `lua_pushglobaltable`

I thought about this:

```
local env = {}
for k,v in pairs(_G) do
    if type(v)=="function" then
        env[k] = v
    end
end
```

But it looks like a pathetic decision. Is anyone have a better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to make `env` inherit from `_G`:

```
setmetatable(env,{__index=_G})
```

Everything in `_G` will be seen in `env`, but if you write to `env` by creating a global variable, it won't affect `_G`, which seems to be what you want.

Unfortunately, `_G` itself is seen in `_G` and so could be used to write to the original environment by doing things like `_G.print=anyvalue`.

To protect `_G`, add:

```
env._G = env
```

Unfortunately, the original `_G` remains available via `package.loaded._G`. This is harder to protect if you want to give access to `package`. The easiest way is to deep copy `_G.package` to `env.package` and change `env.package.loaded._G=env`.

Comment: oh, wait, script will be able to do this: _G.package = 123, because _G will be passed by reference, when I will access it like this: _ENV._G

Comment: Don't forget setting the __metatable field so they can't ```getmetatable(env).__index```.